# Python merging list of lists with varying length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, merge, list-comprehension

I want to write a function that merges a list of lists. The lists can be of varying lengths.

`selected_cells = [[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]], [[7],[8]]]`

My expected output would be `[[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6]]`

I've written the following function

```
def merge(lst1, lst2): 
  print('Merging', lst1, 'and', lst2)
  return [(sub + [lst2[i][-1]]) for i, sub in enumerate(lst1) if i < len(lst2)]

for idx, cell in enumerate(selected_cells):
  if idx < (len(selected_cells)-1):
    print(idx)
    selected_cells[0] = merge(selected_cells[0], selected_cells[idx+1])
    print('Output', selected_cells[0])
```

However this outputs `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]`

I feel like I'm missing something simple here and it's driving me nuts. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is itertools.zip_longest any use?

Comment: What output do you expect if an intermediate list is shorter, e.g. ``[[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5]], [[7],[8], [9]]]``? While it does not exactly match your problem, you may want to take a look at ``zip`` and ``iteratools.zip_longest``.

Comment: I would expect a list of `[[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5]], [[7],[8], [9]]]` to have an output of `[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in comments, you can use `zip_longest` from `itertools` module.

```
>>> selected_cells = [[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]], [[7],[8]]]
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> L = list(zip_longest(*selected_cells))
>>> L
[([1], [4], [7]), ([2], [5], [8]), ([3], [6], None)]
```

And then flatten the tuples and remove the `None` values:

```
>>> [[x[0] for x in t if x] for t in L]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6]]
```

---

Another option is to use a fold (`functools.reduce`):

```
>>> selected_cells = [[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]], [[7],[8]]]
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: [acc[i] + (x[i] if i < len(x) else []) for i in range(len(acc))], selected_cells)
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6]]
```

That's perhaps less intuitive, though.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. itertools is my friend I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip_longest` as stated in the comments, because `zip` will stop at the shortest iterable, for example:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

selected_cells = [[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]], [[7],[8]]]

output = [
    [cell[0] for cell in row if cell is not None] 
    for row in zip_longest(*selected_cells) 
]
print(output)
>>> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6]]
```